# Liquibase check table name length before executing changset

Tags: java, sql, database, liquibase

I am using Liquibase update method from Java code to persist some entities in a PostgreSQL database.

Is there a way to check the length of tables and columns names before Liquibase create them in the database? Something like precondition SQL check or with Java code?

Comment: Are you using an XML changelog? That could probably be done quite easy with an xpath query on the XML.

Comment: yes i am using xml can you explain more ?  I am not familiar with xml xpath query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two possible solutions:

#### Using Java only

You can load the changelog using Liquibase classes, iterate through all `createTable` tags and check the length of the table name and the column names.

A rough outline of the code:

```
File changeLogFile = new File("...");
FileSystemResourceAccessor accessor = new FileSystemResourceAccessor(changeLogFile.getAbsoluteFile().getParent());

DatabaseConnection db = new JdbcConnection(...);
Liquibase lb = new Liquibase(changeLogFile.getAbsolutePath(), accessor, db);

DatabaseChangeLog changeLog = lb.getDatabaseChangeLog();

List<ChangeSet> changeSets = changeLog.getChangeSets();

for (ChangeSet cs : changeSets) {
  for (Change change : changeSet.getChanges()) {
      if (change instanceof CreateTableChange) {
          // check the table that is created
      }
  }
}
```

Another way to obtain the list of changesets, is to use a `ChangeLogIterator` together with a `ShouldRunChangeSetFilter`. With that you would need a `ChangeSetVisitor` to process the changesets.

#### Using XSLT

The following XSLT extracts all table names that are longer then 20 characters and writes that to a HTML file.

You can adjust that to filter on a different length:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>

<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"
                xmlns:lb="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog">
  <xsl:output method="html"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>Tablenames</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <table border="1" class="change-table">
          <tr>
            <td class="table-heading">ChangeSet</td>
            <td class="table-heading">Tablename</td>
            <td class="table-heading">Length of name</td>
          </tr>

          <xsl:apply-templates select="//lb:createTable"/>

        </table>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="lb:createTable">
    <xsl:if test="string-length(@tableName) &gt; 20">
      <tr>
        <td class="table-row change-set"><xsl:value-of select="../@author"/><xsl:text>::</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="../@id"/></td>
        <td class="table-row object-name"><xsl:value-of select="@tableName"/></td>
        <td class="table-row object-name"><xsl:value-of select="string-length(@tableName)"/></td>
      </tr>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```